# Looping firefox tabs in bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a pentest script in bash to be able to loop and open a few tabs in firefox with some parameters

What i am trying to do exactly is open up like 3 tabs like this:

```
http://dmn.com/../etc/passwd
http://dmn.com/../../etc/passwd
http://dmn.com/../../../etc/passwd
```

The code I am working on is like this, I am not a bash scripter so I am still learning:

```
chrs = "%5C.."


COUNTER=0
         while [  $COUNTER -lt 3 ]; do
             firefox -new-tab $chrs$1$2
             let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
         done
```

Variables $1 and $2, will be the url and then the file I am looking for passed through cli argument. I know why this is not working, because all its doing is opening up firefox in three different windows, would i would like it to do is open up 3 different tabs and print out the $chrs as many times as the loop, so the first time it would print it out 1 time, then 2, then 3.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `chrs=/..; for _ in {1..3}; do firefox -new-tab "http://dmn.com$chrs/etc/passwd"; chrs+=/..; done`

Comment: thank you very much for your response, i tried the following but and it almost works, but the problem is now, is it doesn't output the variable $chrs in the url for some reason, below is the following code i used

Comment: $chrs = "../"                                                                                             
$chrs; for _ in {1..3}; do firefox --new-tab $1$chrs$2; $chrs+=$chrs; done

Answer (score 0):

If you need exactly this three urls, then this should do it (without looping):

```
firefox $1{/..,/../..,/../../..}$2
```

Example:

```
$ echo $1
http://google.com
$ echo $2
/etc/passwd
$ firefox $1{/..,/../..,/../../..}$2
```

See [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) for more information.